# Scan 2D array from stdin

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, scanf

As the title says, I just want to paste this input into the program and then every number should be stored in 2D array.

Input:

```
172549683
645873219
389261745
496327851
813456972
257198436
964715328
731682594
528934167
```

My attempt:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array_2d[9][9];

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            scanf_s(" %d", &array_2d[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf("%d", array_2d[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably need `&array_2d[i][j]` in the scanf call.

Comment: yeah i forgot to put it, but it's still not working

Comment: you need `" %1d"` to limit number of digit read, since your numbers are not separated.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how read whole number from a row and then split it into its digits that will be save into a 2D matrix.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array_2d[9][9];
    int value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &value);
        int j = 8;

        while (value != 0) {
            array_2d[i][j--] = value % 10;
            value = value / 10;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf("[%d]", array_2d[i][j]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
}
```